# Microsoft-Graph token using request is to small

Tags: node.js, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to get the access token for my Microsoft-Graph application using request to send a POST request.
The problem is that the token i get as a response is only 1188 characters long. While the token i get when i use Postman is 1461 characters long. Every time i send a request it generates a brand new token, but the one i get through request in nodejs is always 1188 and the one in postman is always 1461.

I have tried different things such as generating a new app api id in Microsoft Azure, but it keeps giving the same results.

This is my code, i took out sensitive information though by replacing it with the word CENSORED.
I'm using the EXACT same request parameters in Postman

```
const endpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/CENSORED/oauth2/token";
    const requestParams = {
      client_id: "CENSORED",
      client_secret: "CENSORED",
      resource: "https://graph.windows.net",
      grant_type: "client_credentials"
    };

    let accessToken = await

    request.post({
      url: endpoint,
      form: requestParams
    }, function (err, response, body) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("error");
      } else {
        console.log("Body=" + body);
        let parsedBody = JSON.parse(body);
        if (parsedBody.error_description) {
          console.log("Error=" + parsedBody.error_description);
        } else {
          getCalendarEvents(parsedBody.access_token);
        }
      }
    });
```

Postman returns an 1461 characters long access token and nodejs request only returns a 1188 characters long access token.

This is what i'm using in Nodejs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

Answer (score 1):

The resource `https://graph.windows.net` is for the legacy [Azure AD Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-graph-api). This is a completely separate API from [the Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/). For the Microsoft Graph, the `resource` should be `https://graph.microsoft.com`:

```
const endpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/token";
    const requestParams = {
      client_id: "{clientid}",
      client_secret: "{clientsecret}",
      resource: "https://graph.microsoft.com",
      grant_type: "client_credentials"
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the resource parameter should be https://graph.microsoft.com instead of https://graph.windows.net.